# Yarn start returns error when executed in a service (Linux Server)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, yarnpkg, systemd

I need to run in the background a web app programmed in react and node which is hosted on a linux server. To do this I have created a service in

> /etc/systemd/system

that does the following:

```
Description=Load React-Node Service.
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/yarn startLinux
WorkingDirectory=/home/developer/projectFolder/
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I run it with `systemctl start webapp.service` I get the following error:

[image]

On the other hand if I run it with `yarn start` directly from ssh it works, but I need to run it through a service so I don't have to have the terminal open. The yarn start and yarn startLinux commands do the following:

> ```
> "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
> "startLinux": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn clientLinux\"",
> "client": "cd frontend && yarn start",
> "clientLinux": "cd frontend && yarn startLinux",
> "server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
> ```

Do you know what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `yarn start` do?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add what the command does